# Manifest Broadcast Receiver No Longer Working

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I set up a Broadcast Receiver in the manifest to tell me when Bluetooth is turning on or off via toast and log messages. The receiver was working fine on both Marshmallow and Pie, but I needed the app to work in the background, so I set up an ongoing notification. After implementing the ongoing notification, I can now receive my toast/log messages after I close the app on my device that's running Marshmallow. I tried to test the app on my device running Pie, but I no longer receive toast/log messages from the receiver, even while the app is opened; I think it stopped working completely. I read the logcat and didn't see anything that helped.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name=".OngoingApp">
        <service android:name=".NotificationsMessagingService">
            <intent-filter android:priority="1">
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".OngoingService" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".BReceivers" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    }
}
```

**BReceivers.kt**

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast

class BReceivers : BroadcastReceiver() {
    companion object {
        const val TAG = "Bluetoooth"
    }

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

        if (intent?.action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
            when(intent?.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR)) {
                BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF -> Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth is OFF")
                BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF ->  Toast.makeText(context, "Bluetooth is turning off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON ->  Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth is ON")
                BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON ->  Toast.makeText(context, "Bluetooth is turning ON", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }

    }

}
```

**OngoingApp.kt**

```
import android.app.Application
import android.content.Intent

class OngoingApp : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        startService(Intent(this, OngoingService::class.java))
    }
}
```

**OngoingService.kt**

```
import android.app.*
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.IBinder
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Build
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MIN


class OngoingService : Service() {


    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        startForeground()
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private fun startForeground() {
        val channelId =
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                initChannels("fearApp_service", "Fear Appeals Service")
            } else {
                // If earlier version channel ID is not used
                // https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#NotificationCompat.Builder(android.content.Context)
                ""
            }
        val notificationIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0
        )
        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId )
        val notification = notificationBuilder
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText("Fear Appeals is running background")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setPriority(PRIORITY_MIN)
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build()

        startForeground(101, notification)

    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private fun initChannels(channelId: String, channelName: String): String {

        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            channelId,
            channelName,
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
        channel.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE
        channel.description = "Ongoing notification to keep the app opened."
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        return channelId
    }
}
```